# Can I make a joint account in UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, bank-account, joint-account

I am an international uni student living with a British student in UK.

Due to complications in dividing money when it comes to buying groceries, we decided it would be best that we open a joint bank account and put money in there regularly (i.e. every week/month) and whenever we go grocery shopping, use the debit card for that account.

Both my rooomate and I have an HSBC Student account.

Is it possible to do what I described or not?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

I see no reason why not, I just opened a joint account with my partner and all we needed was proof of our address and some valid ID - driving licence/passport plus a utility bill worked for us. Of course if you both already bank with HSBC they will already have this information and your bank card may suffice, if you don't have utility bills for example.

Answer (score 3):

I'd strongly advise against this though as you'll create a connection on each of your Credit Reports to the other individual.

If either of you have major debt problems down the line, you'll have to "disassociate" yourselves with the credit agencies to break the link.

**Why not just have an envelope of *cash* that you use to go shopping with?** No hassle and you can keep it safe somewhere in the house...